# Angular 5 - how to do validations on delete file in ng5-fileupload component

Tags: angular, events, angular5

I am using ng5-fileupload component to upload file. Validations are inbuilt in the component service. When i delete the file in the drop zone area file is getting deleted but validation message still remains same since no events are available.
Can someone help me how to call our own method on click of × (delete) or any predefined events available on this component?

```
in html:
<fileUpload></fileUpload>

in typescript:

    validateFiles() {
    //file validations logic
    }

//event to dropzone area when file is dropped in dropzone area

    this.fileUpload.dpbDropDirective.drop$.subscribe((e: DpbFile[]) => {
                // logic to check newly added files
                this.validateFiles();
            });
```

When i remove file in dropzone area file is getting removed and it is handled by angular component but there is no event for this to check validations or do some logic after deleting file

Comment: Please show us your code and try to identify the part which does not work.

Comment: by the look of [this](https://github.com/marcelorafaelfeil/ng5-fileupload/blob/603954d2eec5d9f24eaaa65adcb998ea50a5a6e9/src/components/fileUpload.component.ts#L119), it looks like the observable emits the current list of files just after a file was removed. isn't that useful ?

Comment: Yes change$ observable has the list of files when the file is added or removed. During addFiles newly added file is coming in event and during delete list of files is coming in event. So its difficult to decide which operation has performed on component. I can use this.fileUpload.getFiles() but this is not giving latest files length while adding new files - @Stavm